# Can I do a fresh/reinstall of an OEM PC with the bought Product Key?

Tags: windows-10

I want to rebuild a PC I bought from Newegg (*Which BTW ripped me off so part of the reason to rebuild this foreign mess*).

It came installed with Win 10 Pro which I would like to reinstall, configure like I want, harden and dual boot with Linux.

I tried the usual ways to find the PK in settings and also like this:

```
 (Get-WmiObject -query 'select * from SoftwareLicensingService').OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

Finally found it via the registry which makes me think this is hardcoded somehow.

Can I rebuild this PC and keep Win 10 Pro?  Will it pickup the PK or will that key be useless for a new install?

Comment: If you did not get given a product key on a card or via email then chances are it is a digital entitlement and will activate automatically.

Comment: btw, not sure what point you're trying to make, but unless you're Chinese, or at least South-East Asian, pretty much any computer you buy will be essentially "foreign". Anyone, anywhere else, will just be an assembler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If (as you say) it came with Windows 10 Pro already installed, yes you can re-install Windows.

Determine how much space you wish to allocate to dual boot and partition accordingly.

Then install Windows 10 in the windows partition using the Windows 10 Media Creation Link ISO file (make a bootable USB Key - Rufus).

Install Windows and it will activate.

This is essentially the same as changing your disk drive. Windows keeps the licensing in the Microsoft Licensing Server and it is the same computer.

Good luck - it should all work. I have reinstalled Windows 10 this way myself several times.